# Is the trial at the end of S11E07 a reference to a previous episode?

Tags: its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia

The [*It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472954/) episode "McPoyle vs. Ponderosa: The Trial of the Century" (S11E07) ends with the judge dismissing the whole case and calling in the particpants of the next trial:

> We have Morgan State Delivery vs. the proprietors of one Paddy's Pub.

which of course is the gang yet again. But this makes me wonder, **is this actually a reference to a previous episode of the show**, possibly one of the gang's various schemes involving said "Morgan State Delivery"? (The Ponderosa-McPoyle wedding referenced in the case this episode was about was back in season 8, so maybe the episode possibly referenced at the end was too?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR:  Yes, it is a reference to an earlier episode.

The line you quoted is actually

> We have Morgan **Steak** Delivery vs. the proprietors of one Paddy's Pub.

It is a reference to [S10E4, *Charlie Work*](http://itsalwayssunny.wikia.com/wiki/Charlie_Work_(episode)), in which the gang pretend Paddy's is a restaurant called "Carmine's - A Place For Steaks", and then contaminate a delivery truck full of steaks with chicken parts to rip off the delivery company.  As far as I know, the exact phrase "Morgan Steak Delivery" is never used in the episode, but there is a truck driver who delivers steaks to Paddy's and gets scammed.